# jquery if else textbox number value is not getting validated

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get textbox value to see whether particular textbox has value 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 and depending upon the number i have to perform certain calculation depending upon the number of textbox. Also getting textbox values from another textboxes to perform as percentage for calculation but it is not working properly. Please help. i am using this on class change method.

```
  var StyrPrRev1 = $("#StyrPrRev1").val();  
    var StyrPrRevC1 = $("#StyrPrRevC1").val();  

 //   Prod 2
     var StyrPrRev2 = $("#StyrPrRev2").val();  
     var StyrPrRevC2 = $("#StyrPrRevC2").val();  

 //   Prod 3
     var StyrPrRev3 = $("#StyrPrRev3").val();  
     var StyrPrRevC3 = $("#StyrPrRevC3").val();  

  //  Prod 4
     var StyrPrRev4 = $("#StyrPrRev4").val();  
     var StyrPrRevC4 = $("#StyrPrRevC4").val();  

   // Prod 5
     var StyrPrRev5 = $("#StyrPrRev5").val();  
     var StyrPrRevC5 = $("#StyrPrRevC5").val();  

 //  Revenue Growth %
   // Prod 1
     var StyrPrRevGPa = $("#StyrPrRevGPa").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGPb = $("#StyrPrRevGPb").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGPc = $("#StyrPrRevGPc").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGPd = $("#StyrPrRevGPd").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGPe = $("#StyrPrRevGPe").val();  
  //  Prod 2
     var StyrPrRevGP2a = $("#StyrPrRevGP2a").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP2b = $("#StyrPrRevGP2b").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP2c = $("#StyrPrRevGP2c").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP2d = $("#StyrPrRevGP2d").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP2e = $("#StyrPrRevGP2e").val();  
  //  Prod 3
     var StyrPrRevGP3a = $("#StyrPrRevGP3a").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP3b = $("#StyrPrRevGP3b").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP3c = $("#StyrPrRevGP3c").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP3d = $("#StyrPrRevGP3d").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP3e = $("#StyrPrRevGP3e").val();  
   // Prod 4
     var StyrPrRevGP4a = $("#StyrPrRevGP4a").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP4b = $("#StyrPrRevGP4b").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP4c = $("#StyrPrRevGP4c").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP4d = $("#StyrPrRevGP4d").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP4e = $("#StyrPrRevGP4e").val();  
  //  Prod 5
     var StyrPrRevGP5a = $("#StyrPrRevGP5a").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP5b = $("#StyrPrRevGP5b").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP5c = $("#StyrPrRevGP5c").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP5d = $("#StyrPrRevGP5d").val();  
     var StyrPrRevGP5e = $("#StyrPrRevGP5e").val(); 


      if (StyrPrRev1 = 1)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev1a").val(StyrPrRevC1);
      }
      else 
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev1a").val("0");
      }
      if (StyrPrRev1 = 2)
      { 
      $("#StyrPrRev1b").val(StyrPrRevC1);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP2ba = ((StyrPrRevGP2b * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev1a;
      $("#StyrPrRev1b").val(StyrPrRevGP2ba);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev1 = 3)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev1c").val(StyrPrRevC1);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP2ca = ((StyrPrRevGP2c * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev1b;
      $("#StyrPrRev1c").val(StyrPrRevGP2ca);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev1 = 4)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev1d").val(StyrPrRevC1);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP2da = ((StyrPrRevGP2d * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev1c;
      $("#StyrPrRev1d").val(StyrPrRevGP2da);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev1 = 5)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev1e").val(StyrPrRevC1);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP2ea = ((StyrPrRevGP2e * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev1d;
      $("#StyrPrRev1e").val(StyrPrRevGP2ea);
      }

      if (StyrPrRev2 = 1)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev2a").val(StyrPrRevC2);
      }
      else
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev2a").val("0");
      }
      if (StyrPrRev2 = 2)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev2a").val(StyrPrRevC2);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP3ba = ((StyrPrRevGP3b * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev2a;
      $("#StyrPrRev2b").val(StyrPrRevGP3ba);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev2 = 3)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev2a").val(StyrPrRevC2);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP3ca = ((StyrPrRevGP3c * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev2b;
      $("#StyrPrRev2c").val(StyrPrRevGP3ca);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev2 = 4)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev2a").val(StyrPrRevC2);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP3da = ((StyrPrRevGP3d * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev2c;
      $("#StyrPrRev2d").val(StyrPrRevGP3da);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev2 = 5)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev2a").val(StyrPrRevC2);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP3ea = ((StyrPrRevGP3e * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev2d;
      $("#StyrPrRev2e").val(StyrPrRevGP3ea);
      }

      if (StyrPrRev3 = 1)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev3a").val(StyrPrRevC3);
      }
      else
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev3a").val('0');
      }
      if (StyrPrRev3 = 2)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev3b").val(StyrPrRevC3);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP4ba = ((StyrPrRevGP4b * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev3a;
      $("#StyrPrRev3b").val(StyrPrRevGP4ba);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev3 = 3)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev3c").val(StyrPrRevC3);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP4ca = ((StyrPrRevGP4c * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev3b;
      $("#StyrPrRev3c").val(StyrPrRevGP4ca);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev3 = 4)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev3d").val(StyrPrRevC3);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP4da = ((StyrPrRevGP4d * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev3c;
      $("#StyrPrRev3d").val(StyrPrRevGP4da);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev3 = 5)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev3e").val(StyrPrRevC3);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP4ea = ((StyrPrRevGP4e * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev3d;
      $("#StyrPrRev3e").val(StyrPrRevGP4ea);
      }

      if (StyrPrRev4 = 1)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev4a").val(StyrPrRevC4);
      }
      else
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev4a").val('0');
      }
      if (StyrPrRev4 = 2)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev4b").val(StyrPrRevC4);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP5ba = ((StyrPrRevGP5b * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4a;
      $("#StyrPrRev4b").val(StyrPrRevGP5ba);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev4 = 3)
      {
     $("#StyrPrRev4c").val(StyrPrRevC4);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP5ca = ((StyrPrRevGP5c * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4b;
      $("#StyrPrRev4c").val(StyrPrRevGP5ca);     
      }

      if (StyrPrRev4 = 4)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev4d").val(StyrPrRevC4);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP5da = ((StyrPrRevGP5d * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4c;
      $("#StyrPrRev4d").val(StyrPrRevGP5da);
      }

      if (StyrPrRev4 = 5)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev4e").val(StyrPrRevC4);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP5ea = ((StyrPrRevGP5e * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4d;
      $("#StyrPrRev4e").val(StyrPrRevGP5ea);
      }

      if (StyrPrRev5 = 1)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev5a").val(StyrPrRevC5);
      }
      else
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev5a").val('0');
      }
      if (StyrPrRev5 = 2)
      {
     $("#StyrPrRev5b").val('StyrPrRevC5');
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP7ba = ((StyrPrRevGP5b * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4a;
      $("#StyrPrRev5b").val(StyrPrRevGP7ba);     
      }

      if (StyrPrRev5 = 3)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev5c").val(StyrPrRevC5);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP7ca = ((StyrPrRevGP5c * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4b;
      $("#StyrPrRev5c").val(StyrPrRevGP7ca);
      }
      if (StyrPrRev5 = 4)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev5d").val(StyrPrRevC5);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP7da = ((StyrPrRevGP5d * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4c;
      $("#StyrPrRev5d").val(StyrPrRevGP7da);
      }

      if (StyrPrRev5 = 5)
      {
      $("#StyrPrRev5e").val(StyrPrRevC5);
      }
      else
      {
      var StyrPrRevGP7ea = ((StyrPrRevGP5e * 0.01) + 1) * StyrPrRev4d;
      $("#StyrPrRev5e").val(StyrPrRevGP7ea);    
      }
```

Comment: use '==' in if statement not '='

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parseInt` to convert the retrieved value with `val()` from String to Integer. Then you can compare that Integer with another Integer:

```
if (parseInt(StyrPrRev1, 10) == 1){
    // do stuff
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's not mandatory https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Well, I changed it. You're right and I have my inner peace ;-) :-P

Comment: I used this now, seems like doing validation but my calculation is not working properly yet.

if (parseFloat(StyrPrRev1) == 1)
   {
   $("#StyrPrRev1a").val(StyrPrRevC1);
   }

Comment: You have to convert the values in your calculation also to Integer using `parseInt`

Comment: Means i can't use float ?

Comment: You can use i.e. `parseFloat(StyrPrRev1)` make sure all your numbers are converted and are not strings anymore

Comment: It still does not works. The if else condition is too complicated and it is getting stucked.

Comment: You need to simplify it then... but that wasn't your question and we cannot do your programming for you